# IP PORT-FORWARDING to a HOST fails when requests originate from that HOST (but succeeds from everywhere else) ... (Fedora-36)

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, port-forwarding

I'm unsure if this is where to post this (as opposed to onto the `Network Exchange`), but since it involves Linux and networking is universal, so I'll post it.

I have two Linux computers running `Fedora-36`, as follows:

- **192.168.0.16** -- **host01** (Open ports: **22**, **443**)
- **192.168.0.31** -- **host02**

On my `ISP ROUTER`, I `PORT-FORWARD` requests to port **22** & **443** to **host01**.

Here is my issue issue:

From within `host02`, there are no access issues:

```
user@host02$ nc -vz MY-ISP-WAN-IP 443

Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected / succeeded to MY-ISP-WAN-IP:443.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.04 seconds.


user@host02$ nc -vz MY-ISP-WAN-IP 22

Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected / succeeded to MY-ISP-WAN-IP:22.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.04 seconds.
```

But from within `host01`, itself the destination of the `PORT-FORWARDS`, it gets stuck:

```
user@host01$ nc -vz MY-ISP-WAN-IP 443
Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: TIMEOUT.

user@host01$ nc -vz MY-ISP-WAN-IP 22
Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: TIMEOUT.
```

The same succeeds when specifying it's own name `host01`:

```
root@host01# nc -vz host01 443

Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected / succeeded to 192.168.0.16:443.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.03 seconds.


root@host01# nc -vz host01 22

Ncat: Version 7.92 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected / succeeded to 192.168.0.16:22.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.03 seconds.
```

So `PORT-FORWARD` requests succeed in getting to the destination Host & Ports, except when the requests originate from that destination Host itself.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any nat or output rules in the firewall on host01? Or maybe your ISP Router messes up something

Comment: The router is performing so-called [NAT hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_hairpinning). But it appears it fails when the client and the target are the same. You should for  every case use tcpdump to see what traffic is sent and received when running nc on host01 (without any filter to not miss anything). The problem is most likely on the router. Of course this should be tested with firewall disabled first to not rule out any other problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. It's an ARRIS router. The Netgear before it (which ARRIS replaced) didn't exhibit this problem. So yeah, it's probably a rule in the modem. I'll read up on NAT hairpinning. Thank you.